# How to get minutes value above 59 in Bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I am using [Bootstrap Datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for time of events in a sports game.

The time is measured in minutes in seconds, the event can happen at times like 23:11 and 62:17. The plugin, however, only allows minute values up to 59 minutes.

Can I somehow make the plugin allow other minute values?

Currently I have an input

```
<input type="text" class="form-control event-time" value="00:00">
```

And I bind the plugin like this:

```
$('.event-time').datetimepicker({format: 'mm:ss'});
```

The main reason for using the plugin is that it sanitizes input for user. For example, if user types `4.15`, it is automatically changed to `04:15` upon blur. And invalid values are changed to empty field thus showing the user that the input could not be understood.

Comment: The datetimepicker is used for selecting times during the day, not lengths of time.

Comment: @Barmar what should I use instead?

Comment: Just use a text or number input.

Comment: @Barmar I already have a text input. I need to help user to enter a valid time value which this plugin does great up to 59:59...

Comment: Write a validation function in Javascript that checks if the input is in the proper format.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has a similar problem of sanitizing time input, I ended up writing javascript (jQuery) that autocorrects the input to `minutes:seconds` format.

Here is the function and a minimal example.

Try entering anything like `1:23` `89m29s` or `5468` and it will get translated to some valid value in format `89:29`, often similar to the intended one.

```js
function fixTime(field)
{
  var input = field.val()
  var delimiterPos = input.search(/\D/);   //find the first non-numeric symbol

  //everything numerical before that symbol is minutes
  var minutes = parseInt(input.substring(0, delimiterPos)) || 0;

  //everything numerical after that symbol is seconds
  var seconds = parseInt(input.substring(delimiterPos + 1)) || 0;

  //limit minutes to 100 and seconds to 60. Might be different in other cases
  minutes = minutes % 100;
  seconds = seconds % 60;

  //casting to string
  minutes = '' + minutes;
  seconds = '' + seconds;

  //prepending zeros to make values contain two symbols
  minutes = ('00'+minutes).substring(minutes.length);
  seconds = ('00'+seconds).substring(seconds.length);

  field.val(minutes + ':' + seconds);
}

//usage example
var timeToFix = $('.time-to-fix')
timeToFix.change(function() {
  fixTime(timeToFix);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="time-to-fix">
```